# Migrating CodeIgniter PayPal IPN Handler to Payza IPN Handler

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

Apologies for such a neophyte request but guidance greatly appreciated.  I need to integrate the Payza (formerly AlertPay) IPN handler into the class/function structure that was previously used with PayPal.

My PayPal IPN handler has this construction:

```
class PayPalIPN {

public $paypal_url;
public $socket_url;
public $ipn_response;
public $ipn_data;



function __construct() {
    $this->paypal_url       = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    $this->socket_url       = 'www.paypal.com';
    $this->ipn_response     = '';
}



function validate_ipn($logId = null) {

Do stuff
}
```

The Payza (formerly AlertPay) IPN handler sample code looks like this:

```
define("IPN_V2_HANDLER", "https://secure.payza.com/ipn2.ashx");
define("TOKEN_IDENTIFIER", "token=");

// get the token from Payza
$token = urlencode($_POST['token']);

//preappend the identifier string "token=" 
$token = TOKEN_IDENTIFIER.$token;

/**
 * 
 * Sends the URL encoded TOKEN string to the Payza's IPN handler
 * using cURL and retrieves the response.
 * 
 * variable $response holds the response string from the Payza's IPN V2.
 */

$response = '';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, IPN_V2_HANDLER);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

I started off with this:

```
class PayzaIPN {

public $IPN_V2_HANDLER;
public $TOKEN_IDENTIFIER;
public $response;
public $ipn_data;
public $token;  


//define("TOKEN_IDENTIFIER", "token=");

//define("IPN_V2_HANDLER", "https://secure.payza.com/ipn2.ashx");
//define("IPN_V2_HANDLER", "https://sandbox.Payza.com/sandbox/IPN2.ashx");

function validate_ipn($logId = null)  { 
$this->IPN_V2_HANDLER = 'https://sandbox.Payza.com/sandbox/IPN2.ashx';
$this->token = TOKEN_IDENTIFIER.$token;
```

I am having trouble getting the variables properly declared in the correct structure - getting T_function expected errors and undefined constant errors.

Comment: If you could be more specific with what is throwing which error, and more clear about what you're actually trying to do I could probably help you a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the information in our Dev Center https://dev.payza.com/

You'll find a wealth of information there to help you sort out anything IPN related.

Here is a direct link to the code I believe you are looking for:

https://dev.payza.com/sdks-and-sample-codes/php/ipn/sample-ipn-v2-handler-item.txt

All the best!

Comment: Yes, I had the sample handler but since I am dropping this into an existing CI app I need to do a bit of adapting.  I have gotten a little further with the migration but still having some issues.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't post the code in the comment - 
Here is the code I have implemented thus far:

```
class PayzaIPN {  
function validate_ipn($payzaIPN ='',$logId = null)  {

define("IPN_V2_HANDLER", "https://secure.payza.com/ipn2.ashx");
define("TOKEN_IDENTIFIER", "token=");
$_POST['token'] = ''; 

$token = urlencode($_POST['token']);

$token = TOKEN_IDENTIFIER.$payzaIPN;



$response = '';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, IPN_V2_HANDLER);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if(strlen($response) > 0)
```

When I run the code directly from the browser to test the token handling it shows up in the logs and I get a proper response:
token=47TXhMVgdPrmV3n5aauIZ5CC0MrytYXWjID81pjVnQsEhkSUklPXT3clXZ4SFUFOL5WqepRUpBz5SKomoyPuDw==&
INVALID TOKEN

But when I generate a transaction or resend an IPN from Payza it is not showing up in the log and I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error.  Tony, sounds like you are with Payza -  fantastic to see you here :)